# React Navigation goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I got some error when i have used goBack(null) method in functional component in react navigation

```
function Header({ titleText, navigation}) {
return (
  <Appbar.Header style={styles.headerContainer}>
    <Appbar.BackAction style={styles.backButton} onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} >
     <Text style={styles.back}></Text>
    </Appbar.BackAction>
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Title style={styles.title}>{titleText}</Title>
   </View>
 </Appbar.Header>
 )}
```

Comment: what's the `error` message?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.goBack')

Comment: that mean's you're on first screen, so there's no `goBack()` created, try to update your onPress something like this `onPress={()=>navigation.goBack && navigation.goBack(null)}`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `useNavigation` hook from `@react-navigation/native`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyText() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <Text onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>Go Back</Text>;
}
```

Comment: @react-navigation/native   this is supported with react navigation version-5 but  i have used version-4